# Foreach in JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in JS. I have this sample array:

```
{"record-164": {"tomany": true, "fileName": "164"},"record-165": {"tomany": true, "fileName": "165"}}
```

and code JS:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);

if (data["tomany"] == true && data["fileName"] !=""){
    var fileName = data["fileName"];
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ route('deleteDJS') }}?id=' + fileName + '&type={{ $pageType }}',
        data: {filename: fileName, id: fileName, type: '{{ $pageType }}'},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Delete file" +fileName);
            refreshFileList();
            //updatePhotoList();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    alert('Limit plików został przekroczony. Możesz dodać maksymalnie: ');
    return;
}
```

The above code does not work correctly.
I would like the js script to delete it when the file has the parameter: tomany == true.

The delete function works correctly.

Problem is with file name and tomany parameters - I have many files - not one to delete/parse.

How can I repair this?

Comment: "I have this sample array" ...that's not an **array**, it's an **object**. The difference is important.

Comment: I simply **cannot understand** what is the question here. The *title* and the *description* seem unrelated

Comment: You have to use `data["record-164"]["tomany"]` instead of `data["tomany"]`

Comment: Anyway, `data["tomany"]` will fail because the object doesn't have a property `tomany`. The properties of the top-level object are `record-164` and `record-165`. Each of those then contains another object which has a "tomany" property. You will need to read the data from the correct sub-property. From your description it's not clear if you are trying to read from a specific record only, or if you want to read all of them one after another and delete them all.

Comment: I want to check all objects in turn. If any object has tomany = true - then I want to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for in to iterate your object as below.

```
for(var item in data){

  if (data[item]["tomany"] == true && data[item]["fileName"] !=""){
    // perform your task here 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First that is an object its not array.

You can distinguish object and array using this

starts with `{` -> `object`

example

`const d = {'name':'your-name', 'age':23};`

starts with `[` -> `array`

`const d_array = [{'name':'your-name', 'age':23},{'name':'your-name-2', 'age':26}];`

You can iterate your object like this and then do the ajax.

```js
const data = {"record-164": {"tomany": true, "fileName": "164"},"record-165": {"tomany": true, "fileName": "165"}}


for(let key in data){
  console.log(data[key]["tomany"]);
  console.log(data[key]["fileName"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the data and doing an AJAX call if the conditions are met it might be better to split up the code so you're doing one job at a time.

1) Iterate over the object and produce an array of AJAX promises based on the conditions.

2) Use jQuery's `$.when` to wait until all the calls have been made and then

3) Update the file list based on the results

```js
const data = {"record-164": {"tomany": true, "fileName": "164"}, "record-165": {"tomany": true, "fileName": "165"}};

function doFetch(filename) {
  return $.ajax({ ... });
}

function getPromises(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const { tomany, fileName } = obj;
    if (tomany && filename){
      const promise = doFetch(filename);
      return acc.concat(promise);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

$.when.apply(null, getPromises()).then(result => {
  updateFilenames(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the `data` object and access `tomany` field of each object to decide on deletion.

```
   Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        console.log(key);
        if (data[key]["tomany"] == true && data[key]["fileName"] != "") {
            var fileName = data[key]["fileName"];
            console.log("Going to delete file: " + fileName);
        }
   });
```

Here is your modified code. I have commented out the actual API call part to make it executable.

```js
var json = '{ "record-164": { "tomany": true, "fileName": "164" }, "record-165": { "tomany": true, "fileName": "165" } }';
var data = JSON.parse(json);
function doSomething() {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        console.log(key);
        if (data[key]["tomany"] == true && data[key]["fileName"] != "") {
            var fileName = data[key]["fileName"];
            console.log("Going to delete file: " + fileName);
            // $.ajax({
            //     headers: {
            //         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            //     },
            //     cache: false,
            //     type: 'POST',
            //     url: '{{ route("deleteDJS") }}?id=' + fileName + '&type={{ $pageType }}',
            //     data: { filename: fileName, id: fileName, type: '{{ $pageType }}' },
            //     success: function (data) {
            //         console.log("Delete file" + fileName);
            //         refreshFileList();
            //         //updatePhotoList();
            //     },
            //     error: function (e) {
            //         console.log(e);
            //     }
            // });
            console.log('Limit plików został przekroczony. Możesz dodać maksymalnie: ');
            return;
        }
    });
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this.

```js
var json = {
  "record-164": {
    "tomany": true,
    "fileName": "164"
  },
  "record-165": {
    "tomany": true,
    "fileName": "165"
  }
}

function cleanJson(data, keys) {
  for (let i in data) {
    if (keys.includes(i)){ 
      delete data[i];
      //Do you file delete here
    }else if (typeof data[i] === 'object') cleanJson(data[i], keys)
  }
}
cleanJson(json, 'tomany')
console.log(json)
```